# How to remove action defined in wordpress plugin in theme?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, action

Here is the sample code for my main file.

**main.php**

```
if (! class_exists ( 'TestPlugin' )) {

    class TestPlugin {

        function __construct() {

            add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'dt_wp_footer_1' ) );

             require_once plugin_dir_path ( __FILE__ ) . '/file-1.php';
             if (class_exists ( 'File1' )) {
               $file1 = new File1();
             }          
         }

         function dt_wp_footer_1() {

           echo "<h1> Footer Action 1 </h1>";
         }
     }
}

if (class_exists ( 'TestPlugin' ) ) {

  $test_plugin = new TestPlugin();
}
```

And here is the code for **file-1.php**

```
class File1 {

   function __construct() {
     add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'wp_footer_1' ) );
   }

   function wp_footer_1() {
      echo "<h1> Footer Action : File 1 </h1>";
   }
}
```

And here is theme **functions.php**

Below code will remove action defined in **main.php**

```
global $test_plugin;
remove_action( 'wp_footer', array( $test_plugin, 'dt_wp_footer_1' ) );
```

My question is "How to remove action defined in **file-1.php**?

Comment: remove_action( 'wp_footer', array( new File1(), 'dt_wp_footer_1' ) );

Comment: is any other ways available?